# Eliminando dados iguais com um for

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como faço para eliminar no `FOR` o valor que está vindo na variável resultado. Por exemplo se vim 8:00 expor somente as horas sem 8:00.

```
function buscarHorarios(dataConsu)
{
  medico = $('#umedico').val();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'select2.php', // declarando o script que vai conter os dados
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json', // o tipo de arquivo de cambio que vai ser na usado na requisição
      data:{dataConsu: dataConsu, medico: medico}, 

      success: function (resultado, xhr, status)
      {
        var campoSelect = document.getElementById("uhoraConsult"); // resgatando o campo select

        campoSelect.innerHTML = ''; // limpando o campo select

        for (var i = 8; i < 18; i++) // percorrendo o resultado da requisição
        {
            document.getElementById("uhoraConsult").innerHTML += '<option value="'+ i +'">' + i + ':00</option>';
        }
        $("#uhoraConsult").focus();
      },
      error: function (xhr, error, status)
      {
        alert (error + status);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Caso a variável que você estiver acessando do for possa ser tratada como uma string você pode usar o método substr.
Ex: 
`var x = '8.00';
console.log(x.substr(0,1));`



Passando a posição 0 e 1 você pegará somente o primeiro caracter, no caso o 8.

Comment: @LucasBrogni sabe me dizer se tem como excluir somente um elemento do vetor sem apagar os demais ?

Comment: Se você tiver como fazer alguma condição para tratar, sim.

Comment: @LucasBrogni mano desenrolei um algoritmo em JS e roda somente no CHROME no Firefox não roda.. sabe porque disso?

Comment: Pode ser pela versão do navegador.
Dá uma olhada no https://caniuse.com/ o que pode e o que não pode ser usado em cada navegador.

Comment: @LucasBrogni fiz uma repetição e em certo momento ele começa inserir undefined nos campos que preciso sabe me dizer o por que ?